# Dynamically converting java object class when class name is unknown

Tags: java

```
private Object  getInstance(Appl inNdOut) {
Object cl= null;
// I have to check for 4 instances and do casting
    if (null!=inNdOut) {
         cl = (InAppl)inNdOut;// casting done
         
    }
else{
cl=null;
}
    return cl;
}

public void dta(Appl inNdOut){

if (null != inNdOut) {
                                    
Object something =getInstance(inNdOut);//inNdOut Object  
String theType =String.valueOf(something .getClass ( ).getCanonicalName() ) ;
 //class name to which cast to be done obtained in above
Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(theType);// the object of that class 

//Object newObj = Class.forName(classname).cast(obj);//usual scenario

//my requirement
GeneralApp app =(GeneralApp)newObj //this step is common step after casting, so im trying to reuse it




}
}
```

In simple words,  if I have many instance of scenarios and multiple casting scenario (old code I have been told to not touch it), so if I could get the class name and cast a object to the obtained class name, I could call method from the same.

1. Is the scenario I asked above possible(in code)
2. ```
   Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(theType);// the object of that class
   ```

would it be possible to call a method from theClass?

I know its a little odd questions, if possible please help

Comment: If you know the class statically, just cast to it. And if you don't know the class statically, then how do you know the name of the method to call? Put another way, how can you "know" the method you want to call without knowing what class/interface it belongs to?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I know the classes but if im writing each time i have to write casting for all 4 instance of checks, here im trying to get the class name first and then do the casting making a single call way ie  className object =(className)Indout   after that GeneralApp app =(GeneralApp)   Object, here the second line is common so im trying to reuse that

Comment: Why not just cast to `GeneralApp` to begin with? What's the benefit to the intermediate cast?

Comment: The general app extends the ClassName, if i try to cast directly its giving me error to cast exception,  so that 2 way casting only im able to get the method i want

Comment: If the class is a `GeneralApp` then casting directly will pass. If it's not, then intermediate casting won't help. There's no situation in Java where adding an intermediate cast will make a failed cast succeed. The runtime class is set in stone, and casts simply change the compile-time type information, not the actual structure of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think you're over-complicating things.

> would it be possible to call a method from theClass?

Yes, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do. `theClass` represents a `Class` object. You seem to want to invoke a function on *an instance* of that class. In which case, your code can be simplified greatly.

```
// -> This already get the object instance you want to work with
Object something = getInstance(inNdOut); //inNdOut Object

// -> The name of the class is irrelevant, delete this    
// String theType =String.valueOf(something.getClass().getCanonicalName());

// -> Getting the class from the string that was obtained from the class is circular
// -> and pointless. You already have the class, which is not needed anyway. Delete this.
//class name to which cast to be done obtained in above
Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(theType);// the object of that class 

// -> Casting the object and storing it in an Object type is pointless
//Object newObj = Class.forName(classname).cast(obj);//usual scenario

// -> If the requirements is to get the object as a common base class type,
// -> just cast the original object that already passed your cast checks
//my requirement
// GeneralApp app =(GeneralApp)newObj //this step is common step after casting, so im 

GeneralApp app = (GeneralApp) something;
```

So in summary, your code could just be:

```
GeneralApp app = (GeneralApp) getInstance(inNdOut);
```

Comment: className object =(className)Indout after that                                                  GeneralApp app =(GeneralApp) Object.getmethod, this is what i need, but after Object.getmethod this only the casting is allowed since inside the GeneralApp already field declared for the same

Comment: @Specter I don't understand your comment.